# Sidebar looks bigger ,3d cube looks smaller in multiple page streamlit app

Tags: html, css, streamlit

Versions:
streamlit v1.13.0
python v3.8

When I added the cube-design code to my existing multiple-page code, the side bar appeared larger and the cube and the text on it appeared smaller. How can I make all elements appear proportional and normal?

```
import streamlit as st

# Page config
st.set_page_config(
        page_title= "Multipage App",
        page_icon="")


st.title("Main Page")



# Customization for sidebar
st.markdown('<style>div[class="css-6qob1r e1fqkh3o3"] { background: url("https://media2.giphy.com/media/46hpy8xB3MiHfruixn/giphy.gif");background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size:350%;border:1px solid #36454F; border-top:none;} </style>', unsafe_allow_html=True)

# Hiding the Footer
hide_st_style =" <style>footer {visibility: hidden;}</style>"
st.markdown(hide_st_style, unsafe_allow_html=True)  


cube_design="""
<body>
  <div class="cube">
    <div class="top"> </div>
    <div class="bottom"> </div>
    <div class="left">
      <span>Page</span>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <span>to</span>
    </div>
    <div class="front">
      <span>Welcome</span>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <span>Main</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="shadow">
  </div>
</body>


<style>
 * {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 100px;
}

body {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: white;
  perspective: 20em;
  perspective-origin: 77px 100px;
}

.cube {
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  animation: animate 15s linear infinite;
  height: calc(2em + 20px);
  width: 2em;
}

@keyframes animate {
  to {
    transform: rotateY(-360deg);
  }
}

.shadow {
  position: absolute;
  background: aqua;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateZ(-130px) rotateX(90deg) rotateZ(3deg);
  bottom: calc(50% - 2em - 35px);
  left: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 120px 100px 10px blue, 50px 120px 200px 10px blue;
  filter: blur(100px);
}

.top,
.bottom,
.left,
.right,
.front,
.back {
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  background: aqua;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 50px 10px blue inset, 0 0 0 2em aqua inset;
}

.front {
  transform: translateZ(1em);
}

.back {
  transform: translateZ(-1em);
}

.top {
  transform: translateY(-1em) rotateX(90deg);
}

.bottom {
  transform: translateY(1em) rotateX(90deg);
}

.right {
  transform: translateX(1em) rotateY(90deg);
}

.left {
  transform: translateX(-1em) rotateY(90deg);
}

.right>span,
.front>span,
.left>span,
.back>span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 0.35rem;
  color:#004D40;
  font-family: Lucida Handwriting;
}

.left>span,
.back>span {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotateY(180deg);
}
              
</style>
     

</body>
"""
st.markdown(cube_design, unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

**cube-design as HTML file:**
[image]

**cube-design + side bar in streamlit:**
[image]

Comment: move *and eventually update* this part `perspective: 20em;
  perspective-origin: 77px 100px;` from the body selector to the container where stands the cube.

Comment: I don't know how perspective origin is being changed How are these numbers determined?

Comment: take a look at the spec : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/perspective-origin &  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/perspective  it should start help you understand the use and the effects. perspective-origin needs to be tuned to your needs. The elittle bits of code you shared is not enough for use to reproduce your issue and advise from what you have. My comment was a  hint since we could not efficienthly answer to your question.